# HDR issue on multimonitor setup

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, hdr

I'm on a desktop computer running Win10 Pro 22H2

I have two 4K monitors: [LG C2](https://www.lg.com/us/tvs/lg-oled42c2pua) (main, supports HDR) and [Dell P4317Q](https://www.dell.com/il/en/p/dell-p4317q-monitor/pd) (doesn't support HDR)

The LG monitor is connected via DisplayPort 1.4-HDMI 2.1 cable
The Dell one is connected via DisplayPort 1.4-DisplayPort 1.4 cable

When I enable HDR and go to Task View, on the second monitor some window previews turn black, as well as the wallpaper:

[image: screenshot]

And this is occurring *after* performing a clean Windows installation

Display adapters:

[image: Display adapters screenshot]

Comment: Information required: What are your computer model, display adapter and driver? How are the monitors connected? What are the monitors?

Comment: Updated main post

Answer (score 0):

You may install the
[Dell P4317Q software](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-il/product-support/product/dell-p4317q-monitor/drivers)
to ensure that you have the latest version of the firmware and of the
Windows driver (some monitors have drivers in addition to the Windows
graphics driver).

The "Dell Display Manager Application" might be useful.

If this doesn't help, then search the On Screen Display for more
settings which might be useful.

If you have exhausted all actions with no improvement,
then this is a problem that you will have to live with.

Comment: Seems like firmware updating is [not supported](https://i.imgur.com/6q09c6g.png) on non-USB connection

Comment: A funny and suspicious error message - I never heard of a USB monitor. Did the other software install?

Comment: As regards the display manager, it doesn't have settings regarding HDR, nor can it solve the issue mentioned in the main post

Comment: Right, so no hope for HDR, but the driver might help, and there might be some useful settings. I don't have this monitor, so can't do any testing.